# SparkContext: error initializing SparkContext. java.net.UnknownHostException: master

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am new Spark and Intellij. I have my build.sbt file below:

```
name := "TestSpark"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2","org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.2")
```

I also have TestMain.scala in src/main/scala-2.11/TestMain.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext,SparkConf}
/**
  * Created by tuannv5 on 24/08/2016.
  */
object TestMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Test Spark").set("spark.executor.memory","2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000).filter(_<10000)
    data.foreach(println)

  }
}
```

For some reason when I do Run app in Intellij. I get the error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/08/24 10:29:28 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.2
16/08/24 10:29:29 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/24 10:29:29 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: master: master: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:839)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:420)
    at TestMain$.main(TestMain.scala:8)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: master: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 15 more
16/08/24 10:29:29 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: master: master: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:839)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:420)
    at TestMain$.main(TestMain.scala:8)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: master: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone please explain to me the problem stated in this error? Is this because my dependencies were not installed correctly or is it because of another reason?

Comment: Could you run `hostname` and check the output? Looks like your host name is not set correctly.

Comment: when i run hostname command, the output is: master. But i don't know repair this. Can you explain to me?

Comment: You can just add one line into `/etc/hosts`: `127.0.0.1       master`

Answer (score 3):

Your hostname is not proper.

Type hostname and check whether it's the same in `/etc/hosts`:

For example:

```
root@google:/home/makbul# hostname
```

Google has to same in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1       google
```